# Get name from an element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to submit a list of names from the UL **BY ORDER**. How can I put this into a variable so I can send in ajax post?

In this case I should get something like List with first element xzxc and second sdad

```js
 $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       //How do I get the List of Names from the testCaseList??
       var testCaseNames =
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/create-flow/save',
            data: {testCaseNames: testCaseNames},
            success: (function (code) {

            })
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="testCaseList" class="list-group testCaseList">

  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between" draggable="false" style="">xzxc
    <div class="icons-right"><a class="action-icon" id="edit-xzxc" name="xzxc" draggable="false"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a><a class="action-icon" id="delete-xzxc" name="xzxc" draggable="false"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between" draggable="false" style="">sdad
    <div class="icons-right"><a class="action-icon" id="edit-sdad" name="sdad" draggable="false"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a><a class="action-icon" id="delete-sdad" name="sdad" draggable="false"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></div>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Does by order mean alphabetical order, or by order of appearance in the DOM?

Comment: appearanceeeeee

Comment: Then that is what below solution does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var testCaseNames = []
$('.action-icon:first-of-type').each(function() {
  testCaseNames.push($(this).attr('name'))
})

$('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/create-flow/save',
    data: {
      testCaseNames: testCaseNames
    },
    success: (function(code) {

    })
  });
});

console.log(testCaseNames);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="testCaseList" class="list-group testCaseList">

  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between" draggable="false" style="">xzxc
    <div class="icons-right"><a class="action-icon" id="edit-xzxc" name="xzxc" draggable="false"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a><a class="action-icon" id="delete-xzxc" name="xzxc" draggable="false"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between" draggable="false" style="">sdad
    <div class="icons-right"><a class="action-icon" id="edit-sdad" name="sdad" draggable="false"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a><a class="action-icon" id="delete-sdad" name="sdad" draggable="false"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></div>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
```